# Dynamic control creation using Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I am developing an application which reads XML file and this xml file has the info about the type of controls to be rendered on the browser like textbox,combo etc.
So i am planning to implement the same using Knockout.js.
What will be the best possible View Model design to implement the same.

Consider the XML file as:

```
<Controls>
<PARENTELEMENT>
<ATTR ID="1" VISIBILTY="T" TYPE="COMBOBOX"></ATTR>
<ATTR ID="2" VISIBILTY="N" TYPE="COMBOBOX"></ATTR>
</PARENTELEMENT>
<CHILDELEMENT DEPENDSON="1">
<ATTR ID="3" VISIBILTY="T" TYPE="TEXTBOX" VALUE="ABC"></ATTR>
<ATTR ID="4" VISIBILTY="T" TYPE="COMBOBOX" VALUE="XYZ"></ATTR>
</CHILDELEMENT>
<CHILDELEMENT DEPENDSON="2">
<ATTR ID="5" VISIBILTY="T" TYPE="TEXTBOX" VALUE="DEF"></ATTR>
<ATTR ID="6" VISIBILTY="T" TYPE="COMBOBOX" VALUE="PQR"></ATTR>
</CHILDELEMENT>
</Controls>
```

Expected output should be the parent element controls should get displayed first and if something is selected For ID="1" then CHILDELEMENT that dependson ID="1" should get displayed.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sajesh Nambiar

Comment: Can you post an example of your xml and the expected result ?

Comment: @Damien please see the updates on the question

Comment: Im working on a factory pattern answer for you, hang on ten secs

Comment: Outside of knockout you are going to need some custom logic to create controls and parse the XML.  If after injecting the html elements into the Dom, you have questions on how to set up bindings, I would come back here and show what you have done and what isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some kind of factory pattern?

This utlizes a lib ive written so its not vanilla KO

http://jsfiddle.net/rDUZh/

This is the factory part, the rest is KO magic by my lib

```
this.editors = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(item) {
    return new MyApp.Editors[item.type + "EditorViewModel"](item);
});
```

My lib:
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.BindingConventions

Install using nuget

```
Install-Package Knockout.BindingConventions
```